# why receiving _post in my code doesnt work

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to make a form and I want to handle it but I couldn't.

Here is the form from **`myhome.php`**.

```
<form method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">    <br>
        <img  id="im" src="pic.png" width="30" height="30" />
        <input type="image"  id="su"   " src="sent.png" width="50" height="50" />
        <input type="file" id="my_file" style="display: none;" />
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="fileToUpload" style="display: none;" name="submit"/>       
</form>
```

I am using jQuery to connect the pictures to the inputs.

The problem is that I can't receive the data in `upload.php` - it gives me an empty `_post['submit']` .

**`upload.php`**:

```
    <?php

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {

        echo "its not empty " ;

    } else {
        echo "error";

    }

?>
```

Comment: what does `$check` do?  your jQuery/JS may be playing a part in this, so you may need to show that. Your question is unclear. You've a lot of missing code here.

Comment: You have some mistakes in you code, is this a copy paste of your real code ?

Comment: i am sorry $check was an input but i delete it form the form because its not related ,basically The problem is that it doesnt enter the if statement which  means that _post is empty ,i dont think the problem is from the jquery but i will post  it now

Answer (score 1):

When you submit the form, the action file `upload.php` will receive key=>value variable pairs from each element in the form.

The **name** of each received variable will be the `name="somename"` HTML attribute of each element.

So, just add a `name="somehting"` to your input elements.

```
 <input name="fname" type="text" />
```

Then, on the PHP side:

```
$fn = $_POST['fname'];
```

And you got it.

Comment: i wrote the name on the submit input and on the php side i tried to Receive it by putting _post['name] and it comes out empty

Answer (score 0):

Remove style="display: none;" from submit button and give it opacity 0 instead

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<input type="image"  id="su"   " src="sent.png" width="50" height="50" />
```

To

```
<input type="image"  id="su"    src="sent.png" width="50" height="50" />
```

After that on next page (upload.php) first try

```
echo "<pre>"; print_r($_POST); echo "</pre>";
```

This will give an out of all the post values you are getting .